# Method 'exec' doesn't work in grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs, exec

I have a task that registred in grunt config:

```
grunt.registerTask('test_Branches',          'Run Branches check on windows',       require('PATH').check);
```

And in my branches.test.js I have method check():

```
this.check = function () {
'use strict';
console.log("Execution started\n");
        exec('git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/remotes/origin/  --format='%(committername)', {cwd: currentDir}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('started 1.1');
            if (stderr) {
                console.log('stderr: ' + stderr + "\n");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Authors has been received\n");
            }
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('Execution command error: ' + error + "\n");
            }
        });

};
```

But when I'm trying to execute my task through command line with command:

```
grunt test_Branches
```

I got:

```
C:\PATH>grunt test_Branches
Running "test_Branches" task
Execution started
Done, without errors.
```

What's the problem with my 'exec' method?

Comment: It's seems that I found the solution, guys! You need to use `grunt.task.current.async();` with async functions. So did I and it works now!

Comment: "[*Why doesn't my asynchronous task complete?*](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)"

Comment: Yes, thanks, Jonathan. Unfortunately, I didn't know about that thing and wasted 2 days to found the solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is using `grunt.task.current.async();` for asynchronous functions. As Jonathan Lonowski mentioned, [here](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete) you can find details.